# Can I get DLC weapons for DLC I own from the Shrine?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide

The wayfinder's Glaive weapon only drops in the Drachenfels DLC, which I own.

Weapons can also be acquired by praying at the Shrine. If I pray for a wayfinder melee weapon at the Shrine, is it possible for me to receive a glaive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that DLC weapons are not in the Shrine.  It seems there are some postings about this on Steam and Fatsharks forums.

Here is one from [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/235540/discussions/1/141136086937946692/):

> Is there any reason you didn't add them to the Shrine?
>
> Not trying to be salty there, but it does seem like it completely trashes one of the best loot-adjusting machanics in the game.

The [Fatshark Forum](http://forums.fatsharkgames.com/discussion/4346/new-dlc-weapons):

> After 1.4k hours in-game, level 946 I'm finally tired of grinding. Then I saw they were 2 new interesting weapons in the upcoming DLC, I bought it 9euros (full price).... BUT ! I can't get it with the shrine...
>
> We really need patch : just change the table for the shrine (if the player has the DLC) it's not THAT difficult.

The [official website](http://updates.vermintide.com/release/drachenfels/) states that for the Witch Hunters crossbow, it can only be obtained from the DLC levels:

> This weapon can only drop on levels included in the Drachenfels DLC.

They don't state the same thing for the Glaive, but the website also states that:

> Two destructive new weapons have been added to the roster, and they can be obtained by playing one of the immersive new Drachenfels levels.